# gridbag layout explanation of my code

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

```
this.getContentPanel().add(sortOrderScrollPane, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 5, 5, 0.0, 0.0,
    GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(5, 5, 10,10), 0, 0));  
this.getContentPanel().add(toFirstSortButton, new GridBagConstraints(5, 4, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
    GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 5, 5, 10), 0, 0));
```

The `toFirstSortButton` is taking the entire column. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Change `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` with `GridBagConstraints.NONE`.

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem (and does nothing else)? It would make it easier for us to try things.

Comment: Also read about [`GridBagConstraints.BOTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#BOTH) and other parametrs of [`fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#fill) property.

Answer (score 1):

Change `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` to `GridBagConstraints.NONE`

In addition I would recommend to use the `GridBagLayout` like in following example. It's easier to read and prevents mistakes because you don't need to search for the right parameter anymore.

```
this.getContentPanel().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.getContentPanel().add(sortOrderScrollPane, gbc);
//etc..
```